# Flutter get External Storage Directory and MediaStore with path_provider package

Tags: flutter, android-external-storage

I need to open and save simple text files that may be on the device. For example in Documents, Downloads, etc. Wherever files are available for other programs, in android terminology it is "External Storage"

`path_provider` provides several methods.  One of them `getExternalStorageDirectory()`. The android documentation says:

> This method was deprecated in API level 29. To improve user privacy,
> direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When
> an app targets Build.VERSION_CODES.Q [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment)

If I use methods `path_provider`

`getExternalStorageDirectory()` →  **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp.name/files**
`getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` →  **/data/user/0/myapp.name/app_flutter**

`getExternalStorageDirectories(type: StorageDirectory.documents)` return List which contains

**/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp.name/files/Documents**

**/storage/1CEE-4019/Android/data/myapp.name/files/Documents**

On my android emulator (Api 30) real external documents are located at

**/storage/emulated/0/Documents**

**/storage/emulated/0/Download**

How can I access them? As I understand it, there are no alternatives for`path_provider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage
code snippet

```
String pathDownload = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
print(pathDownload);

String pathDoc = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
print(pathDoc);
```

output

```
I/flutter ( 7361): /storage/emulated/0/Download
I/flutter ( 7361): /storage/emulated/0/Documents
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() async {
    String pathDownload = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    print(pathDownload);

    String pathDoc = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    print(pathDoc);

    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ext_storage uses android_embedding v1 and will soon be discontinued. Also the aauthor of the package is not accepting prs. So the package is unfortunately dead. I f anyone could provide an alternate solution it will be great. Thanks.

Comment: This package was not supporting null safety. Any other alternatives ?

Comment: This is sample kind of plugin it is just new package https://pub.dev/packages/external_path

Comment: Can anyone please suggest some package for the same requirement on iOS?

Answer (score 3):

you va  use external_path package